# android How to change background of a table red white with a delay

Tags: android

I would like to set a background of a table to blink with the collors red + white every 500 millisec for start.The ideea is I want it to implement in this loop inside the program and I don't know how.

```
 if(Integer.parseInt(feedback.getText().toString()) == 0) 
                 {
                        showup.setText("0");
                        btnbool.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        btnbool.setText("FALSE");

                 }
```

I have searched on previous topics but I couldn't find something that work in my code, I don't know how to use a handler to make this happen.There won't be a problem if I call a function to do this.

Comment: `timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService` (p.s then use `runOnUIThread` or `.post` to use the main thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In top of your Activity class implement these:

```
    // isRed flag to set bg to red or white
    boolean isRed = true;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    MyThread thread = new MyThread();

    private class MyThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            showup.setText("0");
            if (isRed){
                btnbool.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                isRed=false;
            }
            else{
                btnbool.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                isRed=true;
            }

            btnbool.setText("FALSE");
            // will run every 500 milliseconds or whatever you wish
            handler.postDelayed(thread, 500);
        }
    }
```

run your thread in your onCreate() :

```
handler.post(thread);
```

to start/stop thread onClick of Button:

on top of your activity:

```
boolean threadStart = true;
```

inside your onclick event:

```
            if (threadStart){
                handler.removeCallbacks(thread);
                threadStart=false;
            }

            else{
                handler.post(thread);
                threadStart=true;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, Accepting the answer in 1 minute.

Comment: Also I already have implemented a button to resset some values, what should I do to stop the blink ?

Answer (score 0):

`Timer` or `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

when you want to launch it

```
executorService.schedule(blinkRunnable, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

the runnable to execute:

```
private Runnable blinkRunnable = new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if(Integer.parseInt(feedback.getText().toString()) == 0) 
    {
         showup.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
             showup.setText("0");
             btnbool.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
             btnbool.setText("FALSE");
           }
        });
    }
    executorService.schedule(blinkRunnable, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); // start again
  }
}
```

P.S You could put the colors in an array, use an index and make something more flexible.